# Symfony2 Locale en_gb issue when using getCountryNames()

Tags: php, symfony, parameters, geolocation, intl

In my parameters.yml I have this:

```
parameters:
    locale: en-gb
```

In my user entity I have this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="Country", type="string", length=2)
 * @Assert\Country(message = "The country '{{ value }}' is not a valid country.")
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 */
private $country;
```

When I use a form, the validation complains that: 
"The country 'US' is not a valid country."

So I had a hunt around in:
/src/Symfony/Component/Validator/Constraints/CountryValidator

And came across:

```
$countries = Intl::getRegionBundle()->getCountryNames();
```

So I stuck that in my code to see what was in it. What was in it, was this:

```
array(1) { ["UM"]=> string(27) "U.S. Minor Outlying Islands" }
```

Rather than the 258 countries it should have.

If I change my locale to **en** instead of **en-gb**, I get the 258 countries in the array.

So, my question is whether my parameters.yml should look like this?

```
parameters:
    locale: en, en-gb
```

Or some such? So that it takes everything from en and overrides what is needed with en-gb.

Or is this a bug? (It seems this was a bug in the version I was using. 2.3.1 and is now fixed in 2.3.5) - Thanks to Ritter for this information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is a bug, as the same code works correctly in Symfony 2.1.

I have raised a bug report here:

https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/9180

Please feel free to add comments, or further information.

Comment: Thanks. I thought it might be. For GB, it only returns the one country which has a different name in British English over US.

Comment: I can confirm that Symfony 2.3.5 resolves the issue. I've just applied it this morning.

Answer (score 0):

I believe if you want to specify multiples you need to use a pipe (|)

So like this

```
locale: en|fr|de
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: That is not the issue. It is the need to combine en-gb with en. Not a choice between the two. Ideally I just want en-gb, but when it comes to getCountryNames, only the difference between en and en-gb is returned. This is less than ideal. So if nothing else, having en-gb override en would be idea. Not sure if that is supported though.

Comment: Ok so I think I am missing something.  So you don't want all 256 countries to be accepted.  What do you want for your end result.  Looks like you want US to be accepted but along with what else?

Comment: At the moment, if my local is set to en-gb, the only country that will be accepted is UM as that is the only country available in getCountryNames (Which Symfony uses to validate against when it comes to a country field.) That is my issue. I am guessing it is either a bug or en-gb is poorly supported.

Comment: I am sure its not a bug as others would have reported by now, but the possibility that en-gb is poorly supported may be.  I found two places the default is set, /src/Symfony/Component/Intl/ResourceBundle/Transformer/Rule/LocaleBundleTransformationRule.php

and

/src/Symfony/Component/Intl/ResourceBundle/Transformer/Rule/RegionBundleTransformationRule.php

Normally I wouldn't suggest messing with these file but it might help determine what is going on.  Good luck!  Sorry I'm not of much help!

Comment: I could see it not being reported as a bug as most people will leave it as en rather than changing it over to en-gb. They need to change it to both en-gb and use the country validation for it to occur. I just can't see how it could be classed as "working as intended". Thanks for looking!